# How does one estimate theta in the Ho-Lee model from a yield curve?

Tags: interest-rates, yield-curve, calibration

I have a yield curve constructed using linear interpolation with data points every 3-months for US treasuries.

I would like to use that calibrate a Ho-Lee model, but I can't wrap my head around how to calibrate theta.

Is there any implementation that I could use (preferably matlab, r or c++) or a detailed description of the algorithm that I could use for reference? I have found some notes on the optimal form of theta*, but it's described in continuous rather than discrete terms, so it's of limited use in my case.

Comment: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18540/ho-lee-model-please-explain/18544#18544

Answer (score 4):

Given the Ho-Lee interest rate model of the form
\begin{align*}
dr_t = \theta_t dt + \sigma dW_t, 
\end{align*}
the price at time $t>0$ of a zero-coupon bond, with maturity $T$ and unit face, has the form
\begin{align*}
B(t, T) &=E\Big(e^{-\int_t^T r_s ds} \mid r_t \Big)\\
&=e^{-(T-t)r_t - \int_t^T (T-u)\theta_u du + \frac{\sigma^2}{6}(T-t)^3}.
\end{align*}
See [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/15956/ho-and-lee-derivation-for-short-rates-model/15962#15962) for the details. In particular,
\begin{align*}
B(0, t) = e^{t\, r_0 - \int_0^t(t-u)\theta_u du + \frac{\sigma^2}{6}t^3}.
\end{align*}
Moreover,
\begin{align*}
\theta_t = \sigma^2 t - \frac{\partial^2 \ln B(0, t)}{\partial t^2},
\end{align*}
which can be computed piecewise-analytically based on the interpolation scheme of the yield curve.