# Ho and lee derivation for short rates model

Tags: stochastic-calculus, short-rate, heath-jarrow-morton

A silly question that is bugging me. I am working my way through Baxter and Rennie (again) and I am getting my wires crossed on the short rate models in particular the straight forward Ho and Lee analysis.

So given the SDE (under the $\mathbb{Q}$ measure)
$$
dr_t = \sigma dW_t +\theta_t dt
$$
where $\theta_t$ is both deterministic and bounded and $\sigma$ is constant.
This becomes
$$
r_t = f(0,t) + \sigma W_t +\int_0^t \theta_s ds
$$
(I hope).

How do I compute the integral
$$
\int_t^T r_sds
$$

Basically it comes down to computing
$$
\int_t^T W_sds
$$
and
$$
\int_t^T \int_0^s \theta_k dk.
$$
From first integral is just book work (though it be nice to see a derivation here other than by parts?)
It is the later which I am not sure about, as the result is apparently 
$$
\int_t^T (T-s)\theta_s ds
$$
Which I am puzzled by?

$\textbf{edit}$
Actually an important piece of information is that I am trying to compute 
$$
-\log\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\int_t^T r_sds}\vert r_t = x\right)=x(T-t) -\frac{1}{6}\sigma^2 (T-t)^3 + \int_0^T (T-s)\theta_sds 
$$

Comment: For integral $\int_t^T\int_0^s \theta_k dk ds$, you can using the switching order technique. Note that the integration domain is a triangle, you need to pay some attention on the integral limits.

Comment: @gordon cheers for your comment . I changed the limits of the integrand (and get the functional form) but for the  integral wrt s I seem to get (0,T)? Is that what you meant by pay attention :)? I feel it is a silly step that I have long forgotten from my analysis days!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For any $s \geq t$, note that
\begin{align*}
r_s = r_t + \sigma\int_t^s dW_u + \int_t^s \theta_u du.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\int_t^T r_s ds &= (T-t)r_t + \sigma\int_t^T\int_t^s dW_u ds + \int_t^T \int_t^s\theta_u du ds\\
&=(T-t)r_t + \sigma\int_t^T\int_u^T ds\, dW_u +\int_t^T\int_u^T\theta_u ds du\\
&=(T-t)r_t + \sigma\int_t^T (T-u)dW_u +\int_t^T (T-u) \theta_u du.
\end{align*}
Moreover,
\begin{align*}
E_Q\Big(e^{-\int_t^T r_s ds} \mid r_t \Big) &= e^{-(T-t)r_t - \int_t^T (T-u) \theta_u du}E_Q\Big(e^{-\sigma\int_t^T (T-u)dW_u} \mid r_t\Big)\\
&=e^{-(T-t)r_t - \int_t^T (T-u) \theta_u du}e^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\int_t^T(T-u)^2 du} \\
&=e^{-(T-t)r_t - \int_t^T (T-u)\theta_u du + \frac{\sigma^2}{6}(T-t)^3}.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
-\ln E_Q\Big(e^{-\int_t^T r_s ds} \mid r_t \Big) = (T-t)r_t + \int_t^T (T-u)\theta_u du - \frac{\sigma^2}{6}(T-t)^3.
\end{align*}
If you really need the integral $\int_t^T\int_0^s \theta_u du ds$, you can proceed as follows: 
\begin{align*}
\int_t^T\int_0^s \theta_u du ds  &= \int_t^T\int_0^t \theta_u du ds + \int_t^T\int_t^s \theta_u du ds \\
&=(T-t)\int_0^t \theta_u ds + \int_t^T\int_u^T \theta_u ds du\\
&=(T-t)\int_0^t \theta_u ds + \int_t^T (T-u)\theta_u du.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I will check the swapping of the integration limits now that I have the target to hit. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It seems this specific passage of the Ho-Lee short rate model has left many readers puzzled, so the authors themselves have expanded on this derivation with a [pdf add-on](https://www.financialcalculus.co.uk/HoLee_HJM.pdf) that can be found at the book website.